# Acessing a list within a different class

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox

I've having trouble populating listbox with the information stored within a different class. This class is called TeacherTools which is where a number of methods are used to control the student objects within that list.

What I'm trying to do is basically add the names of the students to the list but i'm unsure of the syntax.

```
public partial class TeacherTools : Window
{
    private List<Student> studentList = new List<Student>();

    public List<Student> Kids
    {
       get { return studentList; }
       set { studentList = value; }
    }
}

public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    private void beginTest(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        foreach (Student s in Kids) //Unsure here
        {
            studentsList.Items.Add(s.Name);
        }
    }
}
```

Thank you for your time

Comment: How `MainWindow` and `TeacherTools` related?

Comment: They are both individual windows they are not related in anyway, if thats what you mean.

Comment: "Unsure"? I would suggest a basic tutorial for [Instantiating a class](http://csharp.net-tutorials.com/reflection/instantiating-a-class/).

Comment: Since `Student` is your model object. So ideally it should resides somewhere where both window objects can have access to, may be a common `ViewModel`.

Comment: Your code is ambiguous , you need instance of TeacherTools class

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think what you want to do is show the students names in a list box..

```
studentsList.DataSource = teachTool.Kids;
studentsList.DisplayMember = "Name";
```

there is a longer example here
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-GB/library/system.windows.forms.listcontrol.displaymember.aspx

Edit: doing this will give more freedom of control related to the students class
Edit2: the above is for winforms... `ItemSource` and `DisplayMemberPath` seem to be wpf equivalents

[DisplayMemberPath](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.displaymemberpath.aspx)
[ItemSource](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/system.windows.controls.itemscontrol.itemssource.aspx)

Comment: Sadly I believe this is a .Net4.5 feature which i currently don't have access to as I'm using 4.0. The limitations of the network limit the installation of this framework, for now.

Comment: @Melky   its been around since 1.1 - (theres a drop down in link for different versions but all do same thing)

Comment: It must be under a different name cause its not on my list the only thing close is ItemsSource.

Comment: @Melky - appologies, my example is for winforms, itemsource according to msdn seems to be the equivalent, with DisplayMemberPath